# Add a computed field calculated from a junction table to each record of the query result postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, knex.js

I have a rather complex query and I'm not sure if it's doable in psql.

I have 3 tables, checklists, checklist_items and a junction table that maintains a many-to-many relationship between checklist & checklist_items.

**checklists**

```
| id       | description      |
| -------- | ---------------- |
| 01       | 'Upon Dispatch'  |
| 02       | 'Upon Return'    |
```

**checklist_items**

```
| id | type      |elements                  |
| -- | ----------| -------------------------|
| 01 | 'combobox'| []                       |
| 02 | 'text'    | []                       |
| 03 | 'select'  | ['option 1', 'option 2'] |
```

**junction_table**

```
| checklist_id | checklist_item_id |
| ------------ | ----------------- |
| 01           | 01                |
| 01           | 02                |
| 01           | 03                |
| 02           | 02                |
```

I was trying to write a query to get all checklists along with all checklist_items associated with each individual checklist.

Something along these lines

```
[
  {
    id: '01',
    description: 'Upon Dispatch',
    items: [
      {
        id: '01',
        type: 'combobox',
        elements: []
      },
      {
        id: '02',
        type: 'text',
        elements: []
      },
      {
        id: '01',
        type: 'select',
        elements: ['option 1', 'option 2']
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    id: '02',
    description: 'Upon Return',
    items: [
      {
        id: '02',
        type: 'text',
        elements: []
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Current solution is me getting all checklists, iterating over them to find their checklist_items in junction_table, populate checklist_items with a join and add `items` field to each checklist.

```
const checklists = await knex.select('*').from('checklists');
for (let checklist of checklists) {
  let data = await knex('junction_table')
    .join(
      'checklist_items',
      'junction_table.checklist_item_id',
      '=',
      'checklist_items.id'
    )
    .select('id', 'type', 'elements')
    .where({ checklist_id: checklist.id });
  checklist.items = data;
}
```

Is there a better way to achieve this ? preferably without iterating over the checklists array in code.

Comment: I do not see any `SQL` or `postgres` here. Please edit your question tags accordingly. Please supply expected results.

Comment: I did mention psql in the very first line. Doesn't that imply I'm using postgres & sql ? And I have supplied expected results in the first code block right after "something along these lines".

Comment: Do you want a JavaScript solution or a SQL query?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Anything that is better than the current approach ? I would assume that a pure SQL query would be more performant than iterating the whole `checklists` array and making individual queries for each `checklist`